# Running command with quotes within quotes and spaces

Tags: vbscript

Here's the line I need to run

```
C:\program.exe switch "quotedstring"
```

I've tried many attempts of double quotes, double double quotes, and Chr(34) but can't get it working.

```
objShell.Run """C:\program.exe"" & ""switch"" & Chr(34) & ""quotedstring"" & Chr(34)"
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 0):

Don't guess around, use a systematic approach.
Here is an "algorithm" for solving your problem:

- start with the original string
- replace every " by ""
- add " at the beginning and " at the end

Now apply this step by step:

Original:

```
C:\program.exe switch "quotedstring"
```

Replacing " by ""

```
C:\program.exe switch ""quotedstring""
```

Adding " at begin and end:

```
"C:\program.exe switch ""quotedstring"""
```

That should do it.